# Performance comparison between batchching merge and table-valued parameters

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I'd like to optimize the current merge batch for about hundreds of thousands entities, using JDBC 7 and SQL Server 2014.

The prepared statement syntax is somewhat like this:

```sql
BEGIN
DECLARE @field1 type1 = ?;
DECLARE @field2 type2 = ?;
MERGE INTO dbo.target_table AS TARGET
USING (SELECT __field1 = @field1, __field2 = @field2) AS SOURCE
ON (TARGET.field1 = SOURCE.__field1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET field1 = @field1, field2 = @field2
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT (field1, field2) VALUES (@field1, @field2);
END
```

The program then binds POJOs values into the declared above variables.

After reading the documentation of SQL Server, it seems the batched statement will be executed separately on server side, furthermore each merge requires a full table search which could lead to long waiting time.

I wonder whether i can optimize the process by using `DECLARE @my_table_var table(field1 type1, field2 type2)`, inserting data into this `@my_table_var` then performing merge like :

```sql
MERGE INTO dbo.target_table AS TARGET
USING @my_table_var AS SOURCE
ON (TARGET.field1 = @my_table_var.field1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET TARGET.field1 = @my_table_var.field1, TARGET.field2 = @my_table_var.field2
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT (field1, field2) VALUES (@my_table_var.field1, @my_table_var.field2);
```

Comment: Yes, set based approach are better. I would change table variable to temp table though(cardinality estimation).

Comment: Yes.  Use a Table-Valued Paramter: "Using table-valued parameters" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-table-valued-parameters?view=sql-server-ver15  For very large loads you might get better performance by bulk loading a temp table.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-bulk-copy-with-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver15 But a TVP is a bit simpler, and will perform well.

Comment: Consider [Use Caution with SQL Server's MERGE Statement](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)

Comment: Another supplementary question is that given this process will be executed multiple times in the same session, will the re-declaration of table type above raise any exception ?